# SQL Nested select in From caluse

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confuse, can we write SELECT statement in **FROM** clause and if yes why can it be.

```
SELECT v.employee_id, v.last_name, v.lev 
   FROM 
      (SELECT employee_id, last_name, LEVEL lev 
      FROM employees v
      START WITH employee_id = 100 
      CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id) v 
   WHERE (v.employee_id, v.lev) IN
      (SELECT employee_id, 2 FROM employees);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I ask the usage of select in from clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can use. The select clause in the from will act as a inline view(consider it as a temporary table that databse creates to hold the results).
For example:

```
    SELECT sdt sdat
      FROM (SELECT SYSDATE sdt FROM dual);
```

In the above query, SELECT SYSDATE sdt FROM dual is executed first, and output would be like:

```
    sdt
    ---
    08-Dec-2016 16:20:56
```

Then, using this as a temp table(which is called an inline view in such cases), oracle will execute your outer select on this data. Hence SELECT sdt FROM... executes, giving the final output as:

```
    sdat
    ----
    08-Dec-2016 16:20:56
```

Comment: Thank you very much and now i understand that writing **SELECT** statement in **FROM** call **INLINE** view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a recursive cte in sql server which would be something like.....

```
WITH X (employee_id, last_name, lev )
AS (

    SELECT employee_id, last_name, 0 AS lev 
    FROM employees 
    WHERE manager_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name , lev + 1
    FROM employees e
    INNER JOIN x ON x.employee_id = e.manager_id

   )
SELECT v.employee_id, v.last_name, v.lev 
FROM X
WHERE lev = 2
```

Comment: I think he's using Oracle, at the query certainly looks like it.

Comment: The question was tagged with `SQL Server` unless the OP has changed his mind.

Comment: I think the OP already has a functioning query and is just asking about usage of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: sorry all my bros, I ask the use of select in from clause.